# Custom Histogram Input for a very large dataset

Tags: python, elasticsearch, charts, histogram, business-intelligence

I have a usecase of create a histogram that is more meaningful then the default ones.

I have elasticsearch as a datastore where all my numberical data is stored.

It has a number field of price with highly varing values. most of price in the range of 100 to 999 are centered around 399 to 500, from 501 to 999 there are few then again from 999 to 1299 a huge range and so on.

example:

```
 399-500: 1542
 501-999: 7501
 1000-1299: 10214
 1299-2000: 154
 ...
```

While creating histogram of bucket size 200 only 2 of the 8 are having 75% of the bar height others are very small.

If i chose small bucket size then the chart become heavy to render with 1000+ buckets.

If i chose big bucket size then the insights are not useful from the chart plotted.

I want to make a intelligent bucketing where i can split the big buckets in to small ranges `say of 50-70` and in the same time merge the small buckets into single big one `say of 1000`. so that the charts be more meaningful.

Is there a python code for such use case.

Edited:

Due to the two spikes i can neither visualize the flat regions to show the actual variations nor can i show the distribution of power in the spikes to say that price range say 449 to 499 is the most contibuting in the spike of 399 to 500

Comment: You could try to plot the [empirical cumulative distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function): `plt.plot(sorted(observations), np.arange(0, 1, 1 / len(observations)))`

Comment: @BlackBear I didn't inderstand empirical distribution. the aim here is to show the competitive ness of some closely packed ranges liek 399 to 500 and 1000 to 1299 with a bucket size of say 10-20 while removing the flat ranges. because of i set bucket size 10 for whole histogram it will show a flatten curve with two spikes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but if you change the bin-width depending on the amount of data located in a bin there is no longer any reason to use the histogram since it will not give the same amount of information anymore.

Why don't you instead use a normal plot to show the result? A simple code to do so would be the following for example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data_1 = np.random.normal(450, 50, 1542)
data_2 = np.random.normal(700, 200, 7501)
data_3 = np.random.normal(1150, 150, 10214)
data_4 = np.random.normal(1650, 350, 154)

data = np.concatenate((data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4))

nr_of_samples = len(data)
nr_of_bins = 1000
offset = min(data)
range = max(data) - min(data)

bins = np.zeros(nr_of_bins)

for d in data:
    bin_index = int(((d-offset)/range)*nr_of_bins)-1
    bins[bin_index] += 1

plt.plot(np.linspace(min(data), max(data), nr_of_bins), bins)
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel(f"Nr of values, binwidth = {round(range/nr_of_bins,2)}")
plt.show()
```

Giving the following final result:
[image]

Comment: That is the first thing i tried. But it if for the dashboard where we need insightful information and the data is too big for the chart library to render. FYI python is used as Backend and the Frontend is in React.js. Currently the Charts library keeps on handing the browser with the dataset size. Mostly the population is concetracted on certain areas like between 399 to 500 and then 1000 to 1299 then it goes flat for some 5000 and again it goes on to be competitve in a greater range

Comment: But if you increase the binwidth of low-populated ranges then the bin hight will increase in those areas compared to the highly populated ones, giving you useless information?

Comment: Histogram might not the right thing to do i aggree there. that should be the right visualization of such data to provide useful insiights. where i can show the competitiveness of price ranges without having 2 bars on the ends of chart. At the end i want to compress the unwanted data ranges that are taking more space then the bars with actual height. currently most of the histogram is flat in a sense

Comment: Due to the two spikes i can neither visualize the flat regions to show the actual variations nor can i show the distribution of power in the spikes to say that price range say 449 to 499 is the most contibuting in the spike of 399 to 500